# QoS Classification and Drop Rate

Tags: qos, dscp, cos

Sorry if i sound completely senseless,

In CBWFQ,

q1) Does WRED only make sense if there is more than 1 dscp marking in a queue ?

q2) if traffic_typeA is to be handle with higher priority then traffic_typeB,  what would be a better configuration/option below and why >

**Option1**

-> 1 big queue, with higher drop rate for lower priority traffic

> traffic_typeA - tagged AF31
>
> traffic_typeB - tagged AF32
>
> AF31 and AF32 in the same queue

VS

**Option 2**

-> 2 different queues, with 1 queue having a higher priority than the other.

> traffic_typeA - tagged AF31
>
> traffic_typeB - tagged AF41
>
> Both AF31 and AF41 are in different queue

Comment: RED _randomly_ drops packets in a queue to help prevent TCP global synchronization.

Comment: @RonMaupin yeap but if there is only 1 dscp marking / precedence for traffic in the queue, then it does not make sense to have WRED right ?

Comment: If you have multiple TCP connections using the queue, then RED absolutely makes sense. It prevents tail drop, which is what causes TCP global synchronization of the multiple TCP connections. That has nothing to do with precedence. Cisco has simply enhanced RED with a weight, but even if everything is weighted the same, the benefit of RED still exists.

Comment: i see.. thanks!  Edited q2) Could you give your advice on q2) ?

Comment: Your option 1 is handling both traffic types at the same priority, just with different drop probabilities, so it does not seem to fit your second question, which says that one should have a higher priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does WRED only make sense if there is more than 1 dscp marking in a
>   queue ?

Not really.  The point of Weighted RED is to assign different weights to different traffic classes.  Doesn't make much sense if you only have one class.

> What is the difference between 1 big queue, with higher drop rate for
>   lower priority traffic vs. 2 different queues, with 1 queue having a
>   higher priority than the other.

Functionally, nothing.  Using one queue makes the hardware design simpler and cheaper.

Comment: Ron - so it does not make sense for WRED if you only have 1 dscp marking in a queue right ?

Comment: weights are applied to different classes.  If you only have one class, all traffic will have the same weight.

Comment: Ron - thanks , i have edited q2) - can you give your opinion on it ? or it still the same functionally ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you tag traffic -- it matters how you schedule the different queues/depths.  You can configure one queue with different depths or two queues with different priorities to schedule the same.